# `is blocked` error when page was opened from an injected button

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an app where it will inject a button to any page, the button links to an HTML page from my chrome extension.

The page opens, but I received the following error on the page.

```
hnplemhgefnimaejljoniapgopbpfcad is blocked
Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.
Try disabling your extensions.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

However, if I refresh the page, the page starts to work. Does anybody know why?

---

Example app:

**content.js**

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');

const newNode = document.createElement('div');
newNode.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; padding: 15px; background: yellow; margin: 100px; z-index:99999;')
newNode.innerHTML = `<a href="chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/example.html" target="_BLANK">Example Page</a>`;

body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', newNode);
```

**example.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>example</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "example",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["declarativeContent", "contextMenus"],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"], 
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow links to chrome:// or chrome-extension:// URLs in web pages. Add a click listener which will send a message to the background script that will use chrome.tabs.create. Alternatively, list that file in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: This helped me with figuring out how to get AWS Amplify Federated sign in working on the options page of my extension.